# installing 2 ggplot in R and getting an error

Tags: r, installation, error-handling

i am trying to install ggplot 2 into R . The instalation works well but when i write:

```
  library("ggplot2")
```

i get an error:

```
 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, 
.libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘lifecycle’
```

i looked online to find any help, restarted R nothing worked.
i insataled the lifrcycle package didnt help at all.
instald ggplot2 from the tool bar  how can i fix this ?
thank you :)

Comment: What was the error message after you installed lifecycle and then called `library("lifecycle")`?

Comment: * installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing 'C:/Users/agns1/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/lifecycle'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: library("lifecycle")
Error in library("lifecycle") : there is no package called ‘lifecycle’

Comment: `rlang` is at the root of alot of these issues. Do you have `rtools` installed or some way to compile?

Comment: Seeing the error " namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required" means you already have an old version of rlang loaded into R so it can't be updated. The easiest way around that is to restart R so nothing is loaded, then run `install.packages("rlang")` to make sure that package is properly updated. Make sure you don't have any code that automatically runs when you start R that would load that package before you can update it.

Comment: sadly no :) should i install it ?

Comment: what sould  i do when  rlang is updated?

Comment: it didnt work :byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required

Comment: install.packages("rlang")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/agns1/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
rlang  0.4.5 0.4.12              TRUE

Comment: *** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rlang'
* removing 'C:/Users/agns1/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rlang'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/agns1/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rlang'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/agns1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpkbPHb0/downloaded_packages/rlang_0.4.10.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: `make` not found seems like Rtools is not properly installed or not being recognized by R. If you have it installed, where is it installed? Paths with spaces in them have been a problem (so windows is ... a problem), so I have mine installed as `C:\Rtools40`.

Comment: okay / what can i do about it?

Comment: [Install Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/). This isn't an R package, but a separate utility program. Then restart R and `install.packages("rlang")`.

Comment: It looks like from the error messages that you are using R 3.5. It might be a good time to update to at least R 4.1. In doing so you'll have to reinstall most packages which will make this particular problem go away. You do not need to worry about Rtools at all. I would suggest you avoid it and just use the pre-built binary versions of packages and not try to compile on your own if you don't have to.

Comment: thank  you :) i update R and it worked :)